# Permisos para bucket especifico y folder especifico

Tags: amazon-s3

verán tengo un s3 Bucket en Amazon, con la siguiente estructura:

```
Carpeta "Home" :
 - Usuario1
 - Usuario2
 - Usuario3
```

Deseo crear un usuario IAM especifico para cada usuario, y de esta manera, cada usuario tenga acceso especifico a su propia carpeta y subcarpetas.

Entiendo que tendría que crear un usuario diferente para que cada usuario accesa a su respectiva carpeta, el problema es que ¿Como quedaría el JSON de los privilegios?

Actualmente uso este, pero ese da acceso a todas las carpetas, lo que yo necesito es especificar solo 1 carpeta con todos sus archivos y subcarpetas:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mibucket"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
]
```

}

ya he intentado de muchas maneras siguiendo los manuales de amazón, pero nadamás no tiene ganas :(

gracias por su ayuda. Saludos.

ACTUALIZADO:

Con la ayuda de Leonardo he logrado hacer lo siguiente:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mibucket"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mibucket/home/Usuario/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Sin embargo el código anterior me permite acceder a la carpeta (especificando la ruta claro está), pero no me deja cargar archivos : (

https://prnt.sc/k8mrs9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agadesco la ayuda, al final encontré lo que necesitaba.

```html
{
 "Version":"2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
     "Action": ["s3:ListAllMyBuckets", "s3:GetBucketLocation"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::*"]
   },
  {
     "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
     "Condition":{"StringEquals":{"s3:prefix":["","home/"],"s3:delimiter":["/"]}}
    },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company"],
     "Condition":{"StringLike":{"s3:prefix":["home/David/*"]}}
   },
   {
     "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": ["s3:*"],
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::my-company/home/David/*"]
   }
 ]
}
```

Fuente: https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-s3-user-specific-folder/

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería funcionare, no entiendo bien tu estructura pero suponiendo que tu bucket se llama `mibucket` y dentro de este bucket quieres tener una estructura como la siguiente:

Home/Usuario1

Home/Usuario2

Home/Usuario3

Acá cada iam tendrías que aplicarle una política como la siguiente:

```
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mibucket/Home/Usuario1"]
   },
   {
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Action": ["s3:*"],
     "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::mibucket/Home/Usuario1/*"]
   }
 ]
}
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

**EDIT1:**

Ten en cuenta que cada usuario solo puede listar su carpeta especifica por lo que si por ejemplo te conectas para probar con cyberduck o lo que fuere, tienes que especificar que la carpeta a mostrar es la que le corresponde al usuario, por ejemplo "Home/Usuario1".

**EDIT2:**

Como puse en el comentario al parecer el programa que usas para conectarte quiere listar la raiz del bucket, pero cada usuario en la policy que te pase solo puede listar su carpeta. 
No conozco ese programa pero si quieres probar con cyberduck puedes especificar que carpeta se esta accediendo cuando uso se conecta, por lo que no tienes que tener problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este programa si en la parte que dice path pones mibucket/Home/Usuario1 deberias poder conectarte.

**EDIT3:**

Agrego la policy que se encuentra en la pagina oficial para restringir acceso a carpetas individuales por usuario, documentado [aqui](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_home-directory-console.html):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET-NAME>",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "home/",
                        "home/${aws:username}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET-NAME>/home/${aws:username}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<BUCKET-NAME>/home/${aws:username}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente, la estructura que me comentas es tal cual la tengo, voy a probar el código que me compartes y te platico como me fue. Aunque ya había probado con algo similar lo intentaré. Gracias.

Comment: Mira, esto es lo que me aparece, estoy utulizando TnTDrive para poder configurarle a cada usuario su carpeta correspondiente, pero no lo logro, estoy usando tu código tal cual, (obvio cambiando el nombre del bucket y del usuario, la carpeta raiz se llama Home igualmente.) https://prnt.sc/k8ltby

Comment: cuando configuras la coneccion le especificas la carpeta correspondiente a ese usuario?

Comment: No, es que nisiquiera me deja cargar el Bucket

Comment: Si gustas te puedo compartir un Acces ID y Key de prueba. :/

Comment: Puedes probar con mi edit 2, la primer police que te pase un usuario solo puede listar su carpeta, por lo que ese programa que estas usando por lo que veo quiere listar la carpeta raiz y ahi es donde esta fallando, tal vez este edit te permita seleccionarla.

Comment: Excelente tienes toda la razón, editando el path se resuelve el problema. ¿Sabes? Estoy infinitamente agradecido contigo, eres muy amable muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Amigo, ya me pude conectar pero que crees? No puedo cargar archivos :(  https://prnt.sc/k8mkmr

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda.